# How to not get negative values in the forecast?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima, fitting

**Data** - Monthly Rainfall of a region for the past 20 years.

**Objective** - To Forecast for the next 2 years.

In the collected data, 10 out of 13 values for January are 0s and the other three are (1.9, 0.9, 0.2). When done forecasting for the next 2 years, The values obtained for January are negative (i.e. -1.66, -0.49). Since I am dealing with Rainfall data is there a way to get the forecasting values for January to be 0 or positive.

Comment: How are you defining 'better' here?  Is there some holdout testing you are doing?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162598/a-model-for-non-negative-data-with-many-zeros-pros-and-cons-of-tweedie-glm also https://www.google.com/search?q=time+series+forecasting+negative+values+site:stackoverflow.com&client=ubuntu&hs=QWx&channel=fs&sxsrf=AOaemvI1uBYm7amxCG04XUv0dWRuWRlHag:1636097653178&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiesb3b2oD0AhUKIbkGHYW5AVcQrQIoBHoECDYQBQ&biw=1235&bih=645&dpr=1.5